# Image redirection problem

Tags: commerce, media

I have created a product teaser using views and included images as one of the fields (by including  ***(Products referenced by field_product) Field: Images*** ). In the settings for  **" (Products referenced by field_product) Field: Images "** I linked the image to **"content"**. But the result is something different. Instead of linking the image to **"original content"**, Drupal is linking it to the edit page of that content. Please help me fix this problem. I want my **"product Image"** to link to its **"original content(the product itself)"**.[I Followed this procdure to create product teaser (Advanced Product Display Listing using Views)](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/setting-product-catalog).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these steps to achieve what you want.

- Add a field in your views **Content:Nid**.
- Rearrange the field & place above added field at the top of yours **(Products referenced by field_product) Field: Images**.
- Edit **(Products referenced by field_product) Field: Images** & set **Link image to** `Nothing`.
- Click on **Rewrite results** & check **Output this field as a link**.
- Paste `node/[nid]` token in **Link path**.
- Save it & you are done :)

Comment: should I select the "Link this field to the original piece of content " optin in "Content:Nid".

Comment: Great job Mr. RajeevK. Thanks a lot. It was of great help. Thank you once again